# Create Word Cloud after Action Button clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to re run the creation of Word Cloud after the user clicks a button. Currently it's not re running :(. The basic of the app is that a user types in some keywords (textInput) and after the click (actionButton) it should use the new provided text and run the code.

```
SERVER.R
wc_data <- reactive({
      input$Update
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Progressing corpus")
          query<-get_sql_query(input$key)
          wc_file <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
          wc_file<-wc_file[,3]
          wc_corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(wc_file))
          wc_corpus_clean<-tm_map(wc_corpus, tolower)
          wc_corpus_clean<-tm_map(wc_corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
          wc_corpus_clean<-tm_map(wc_corpus_clean, removeWords, stopwords::stopwords(language = "en", source = "stopwords-iso"))
          wc_corpus_clean<-tm_map(wc_corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
          wc_corpus_clean<-tm_map(wc_corpus_clean, stemDocument)
        })
      })
    })
    wordcloud_rep<-repeatable(wordcloud)

    output$wcplot<-renderPlot({
      withProgress({
        setProgress(message = "Creating wordcloud...")
        wc_corpus<-wc_data()
        #dev.new(width = 1000, height = 1000, unit = "px")
        wordcloud(wc_corpus, max.words=input$max,min.freq = input$freq, scale=c(10,0.5), colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"), random.order = F, rot.per = 0.35)
      })
    })
UI.R
textInput("key", label = "Enter the keywords on the basis of which Word Cloud will be created:", value = "search customer expensive"),
                 actionButton("Update","Update")
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Could you post the complete code ? We don't know what are `input$max` and other things. Make a reproducible example to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `renderPlot` instead `renderWordcloud`. You can find more info [here.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ECharts2Shiny/versions/0.2.13/topics/renderWordcloud)

Comment: renderPlot creates the WordCloud